# How to make this join between multiple tables in mysql work

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-rds

I have three tables, patient_set, user and map_patient_set_user. I'm trying to do an inner join between patient_set and user and also patient_set and map_patient_set_user in a single query. The query should return all the patient_sets for which a given user is the creator or care_coordinator. But patient sets can also be returned if they have the required permission (specified in map_patient_set_user). The following query ends up returning data from only the map_patient_set_user and ignores the join between patient_set and user. What should be the correct way to implement this join.

```
//Query
SELECT *
  FROM (
    patient_set AS a 
          JOIN user AS b ON a.creator_id = b.user_id OR a.care_coordinator = b.user_id
          JOIN map_patient_set_user AS m ON a.patient_set_id = m.patient_set_id
   )
  WHERE 
    b.user_id = UUID_TO_BIN_F(:id)
    OR 
    m.permission = 'view_all'
  ORDER BY created DESC;


//Tables
CREATE TABLE user (
    user_id BINARY(16) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    org_id INT UNSIGNED,
    FOREIGN KEY (org_id) REFERENCES organization(org_id),
    lru_patient_set_id BINARY(16)
);

CREATE TABLE patient_set (
    patient_set_id BINARY(16) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    creator_id BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (creator_id) REFERENCES user(user_id), 
    created DATETIME NOT NULL, 
    last_updated DATETIME,
    care_coordinator BINARY(16),
    FOREIGN KEY (care_coordinator) REFERENCES user(user_id),
    num_patient_updates INT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE map_patient_set_user (
    patient_set_id BINARY(16),
    user_id BINARY(16),
    permission ENUM('view_no_personal', 'view_all', 'edit_all'),
    FOREIGN KEY(patient_set_id) REFERENCES patient_set(patient_set_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES user(user_id)
);
```

Comment: If you have rows that should be returned that don't join with the other table, use multiple queries that you combine using `UNION`.

Comment: in mysql JOIN is the same as INNER JOIN. You probably need LEFT JOIN